# Cannot invoke "java.io.File.isFile()" because "this.inputFile" is null

Tags: maven, quickfixj

I met a problem when trying to build [Quickfixj Project](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj) on Windows 10.

I tried the command using Git:

`$ mvn clean package -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -PskipBundlePlugin`

and it returned error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.4.2:single (bin-assembly) on project quickfixj-distribution: Execution bin-assembly of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.4.2:single failed: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.isFile()" because "this.inputFile" is null -`

I've never met such problem and I searched online but no relevant solutions were found.

Shall I reinstall maven or other solutions recommended? Thanks!

Comment: The references project is using Make not Maven !!! https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix#building-and-installing

Comment: You've tagged `quickfixj`, the Java port...but you're linking to the original `c` project, which of course doesn't build with `maven`. Did you mean https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj ?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug with the QuickFIX/J build process.

If you omit `-PskipBundlePlugin` the build will succeed.

Edit: this should be fixed for QFJ 3.0.0 with this pull request: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/pull/615

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for me with mac m1, on vscode;

I just changed the version in the pom.xml file to:
maven-assembly-plugin-version>3.1.0</maven-assembly-plugin-version
and it worked for me.

in addition to that I Installed some apache extension for vscode.